# AJAX function is not called in listener

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

function validate() is not called in listener or something else causes the error. THe data is not added to DB. index.php:
function validate() is not called in listener or something else causes the error. THe data is not added to DB. index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){



            $("#add_button").click(function(){

                validate();

            });

        });

        function validate(){

            $.post("ajax_controller.php",

                {

                    act:"add",
                    subject:$("#subject").val(),
                    description:$("#description").val(),
                    price:$("#price").val(),
                    semester:$("#semester").val()

                }

            );

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="add.php" method="post" id = "login_form">
        <input type="hidden" value="add" name = "act">
        <input type="text" name = "subject" id = "subject">
        <input type="text" name = "description" id = "description">
            <input type="text" name = "price" id = "price">
        <input type="text" name = "semester" id = "semester">

        <input type="button" id = "add_button" value = "add">

    </form>
</body>
```

and ajax_controller.php:

```
<?php
    echo "asd";
    if(isset($_POST['act'])){
        if($_POST['act']=='add'){

            $subject= $_POST['subject'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $semester = $_POST['semester'];

            $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","subjects");

            $query = $connection->query("insert into subjects(id, name, desctiption, price, semester) values(NULL, \"".$subject."\", \"".$description."\",  ".$price.", ".$semester." )");



        }
    }
?>
```

jquery library was added. Thank you.

Comment: Check for any console errors in your browser...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao There was none.

Comment: I know it's a cliché.. but sanitize your data! Never, ever, never, never, ever put things in your database without escaping it... or better yet.. use PDO and prepared statements! (This can't be mentioned enough)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am sorry for that, I am very new to web and even not going to study it deeper :)

Comment: ...and if the validate() function in js never gets called, it's not a PHP-question.

Comment: ajax is getting called. I checked in my system...

Comment: Even values are getting passed.

Comment: @БейбутТукибаев you have added echo in your php page, are they getting echoed?? Check in console for that.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju no, when i click "add" nothing is shown. How did you get echoed?

Comment: it didnt echo, but it was showing 404 error since i didnt had that page. So problem is in php.

Comment: If the error is a 404 then the path to the ajax_controller.php is wrong. Is the PHP file in the same directory as the web page?  In addition, you're not checking your queries or connection for errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Answer (score 0):

change the coding in ajax_controller.php

```
       <?php
          if(isset($_POST['act'])){
              if($_POST['act']=='add'){

                 $subject= $_POST['subject'];
                 $description = $_POST['description'];
                 $price = $_POST['price'];
                 $semester = $_POST['semester'];

                 $connection = mysqli("localhost","root","","subjects");

                 $query = mysqli_query($connection,"insert into subjects(id, name, desctiption, price, semester) values(NULL, \"".$subject."\", \"".$description."\",  ".$price.", ".$semester." )");
              }
           }
       ?>
```

now the data is add to db

Comment: Just brief what changes you have made.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.